# Solving No parameterless constructor defined for type of \u0027System.String\u0027

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, webmethod

I've read through other responses to the same question, haven't been able to solve this. I'm trying to post a JSON string to my server (.NET), parse it and store some of the values - code is below. Everything works (ie the data ends up in my database, but it still throws the 500 error). Have looked into it with Fiddler etc but no success

There are probably plenty of other issues in my code - it's just a bit of experimentation, for now, but would appreciate any advice...

First, the jQuery post:

```
function PostData(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/PostData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ postedData: value }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log("success: " + msg.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.log("error:" + xhr.statusText + "  " + textStatus + "  " + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Next, the server side gear:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string PostData(string postedData)
{
    _PostData(postedData);
    return null;
}

public static void _PostData(string postedData)
{
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(postedData);
    string id = (string)o.SelectToken("id");

    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Table1 (userId, data) VALUES (@userIdValue, @dataValue)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIdValue", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataValue", postedData);

            sql.Open();
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An error 500 means that there is something wrong on the server side. Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7559676/266919

Comment: Yes, it is server side. Thought though the problem could be related to my client-side actions.

Comment: Look at the duplicate ... It could be the quotes ...

Comment: The class `System.String` has many instance constructors, but none of them are parameterless, i.e. takes zero arguments. Therefore you can't say `new String()` in C#. And you can't use `string` for a type parameter `T` of some generic method or class if `T` has the constraint `where T : new()`. (Also, a class trying to derive from `string` would need to chain a base constructor with parameters, but `string` is `sealed`.) But don't you have a stack trace belonging to the message `No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'`? That would point out where your problem is.

Comment: Sorted it out - \" in my JSON object solved it, as per Obalix link above